# Numerical reference encoding for Perl

Tags: perl, character-encoding

I'm having an issue with Perl. I'm trying to use [HTML::Entities](http://www.metacpan.org/module/HTML::Entities) to encode a string which it does. However I'm trying to convert it into a numerical reference. e.g:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Protocol::https;
use HTML::Entities;


my $str = "vis-à-vis Beyoncé's naïve\npapier-mâché résumé";
$str = encode_entities($str);

print $str;
```

this out puts

```
vis-&agrave;-vis Beyonc&eacute;&#39;s na&iuml;
papier-m&acirc;ch&eacute; r&eacute;sum&eacute;
```

Instead I would like to output

```
vis-&#224;-vis beyonc&#232; na&#239;ve\npapier-m&#226;ch&#239; r&#239;sum&#239;";
```

The issue here is I don't wanna use this type of encoding (`&agrave;`) but rather use this type (`&#224;`).

Comment: use subroutine encode_entities_numeric. This routine is not exported by default.

Comment: @Pradeep please add that as an answer.

Comment: @Pradeep By using the this i get (&#xhexnum;) however what I would like is the unicode (&#num;). i.e I get 

`vis-&#xE0;-vis Beyonc&#xE9;&#x27;s na&#xEF;ve
papier-m&#xE2;ch&#xE9; r&#xE9;sum&#xE9; `

instead of the

`vis-&#224;-vis beyonc&#232; na&#239;ve\npapier-m&#226;ch&#239; r&#239;sum&#239;";`

See the difference?

Comment: Jethro: why do you care whether your numbers are in hex or decimal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a simple solution using regex, to get what you need, here's the code below:

```
use HTML::Entities qw[encode_entities_numeric];
use utf8;

my $str = "vis-à-vis Beyoncé's naïve\npapier-mâché résumé";
$str = encode_entities_numeric($str);

print "\n=======\n",$str,"\n=======\n";

$str =~ s/&#x([A-F0-9]+);/sprintf('&#%s;',hex($1))/ge;

print "\n=======\n",$str,"\n=======\n";
```

The output looks something like this:

```
=======
vis-&#xE0;-vis Beyonc&#xE9;&#x27;s na&#xEF;ve
papier-m&#xE2;ch&#xE9; r&#xE9;sum&#xE9;
=======

=======
vis-&#224;-vis Beyonc&#233;&#39;s na&#239;ve
papier-m&#226;ch&#233; r&#233;sum&#233;
=======
```

Find the pattern of the hex code, and convert it to the decimal format.

Comment: Hi @pradeep This is still not giving the desirable results please note the unicode for é is `&#239;` yet the regex translates this into `&#233` so the output of the code is `vis-A -vis BeyoncAc's naA-ve papier-mAcchAc rAcsumAc` instead of `vis-à-vis beyoncè naive\npapier-machi risumi`.

Comment: @JETHROKANE code for **é** is 233, you can verify it at http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=oct&unicodeinhtml=dec&htmlent=1 & for the incorrect output, check if your browser/terminal supports utf8